# Can we Ping extension from DialPlan?

Tags: asterisk, sip

Requirement:
Send SIP Qualify to extension from dialplan.

Why?
If the extension is NOT_IN_USE then a different set of functions will be called & if extension is UNREACHABLE the different.

But if my device suddenly breaks connection, asterisk takes time to change the status, the time depends on qualifyfreq value, & in between this time if other device makes call it goes to wrong set of functions. Hence I would like to call Peer_poke on top of everything in dialplan, so that correct status of the extension is updated & then go to right set of function calls.

Keeping in mind I can not reduce qualifyfreq value below 60secs.

Tried reading as much as possible for all available functions in dialplan, nothing served my purpose, I can check the status of extension, but the status is not the current one it depends on last ping sent by Asterisk Server & I need Asterisk to ping the device and give me the current status.

Comment: Why can't you reduce qualify frequency below 60?

Comment: @miken32 : There are many devices which dont like frequent ping from server due to battery constraints. Also even if I reduce it to lets say 5 secs, still there will be a 5 seconds gap, where it can show wrong status, that just reduces the probability of the issue doesnt fix it.

Comment: Correct setup should be ping FROM device, not backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using sip message command(but other side should ignore messages or not support it).

You also can setup qualify,qualifyfreq in sip.conf after that check SIPPEER function.

Sure you also can write special function which will do ping, but with that function you will have same issue(i.e if no connection, unpredicatable waiting time for response) and you have rewrite ALOT of source code for that.

At current moment no way do that in chan_sip without much coding, so this function is not realized.

As other option you can ping device using external app, using libpcap for capture response and sending asterisk port in udp packet(udp not check source port). Anyway that will require special coding and some skills.

Comment: wow that was quick, really appreciate your answer, i was coming to same conclusions but all looked pretty much complicated code, the message idea seams good will try it tomorrow.

Comment: sending empty message just before all other logic did worked for me, it didn't do exactly what I thought in beginning that it will change the DEVICE_STATE, but I just looked for message to be delivered successfully then proceeded with logic, if it dont deliver successfully in X seconds then hangup.

Comment: There is also PUSH mechanism in IOS and Android especialy for that. It ask remote device re-register before incomign call.

Comment: We are doing the same things, but problem is if we call DIAL when device is offline but status is not changed in Asterisk, then DIAL will keep trying the call on old channel, the new channel created by device after receiving PUSH is considered only on next call.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, hence we have to build a mechanism in Asterisk to wait until device registers then call DIAL.

Comment: Sure, becuase dial already sended message to host and retransmit do same message. You can dial SIP/something&Local/something@delay_context&Local/something@delay_context2, after that in context do dial with dleay of 10sec, on other with delay of 20 sec etc. But that way you can get multiple incoming calls on ext.